# How does a foreach loop with a LinkedList behave?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am not sure about a LinkedList's behavior within a foreach loop. e.g:

```
LinkedList<Apple> apples = new LinkedList<Apple>();

public Apple apple(String colour) {
    for (Apple apple : apples) {
        if (apple.getColour().equals(colour)) {
            dosomething();
            return apple;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Imagine there are many red apples spread over the list, not in any particular order. When it is called like this:

```
apple("Red");
```

.. would it return the first red apple or the last? If not, how exactly would it behave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An enhanced-for loop behaves [just like an iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) going from the beginning of the list to the end.  It will act on the **first** element that matches your condition.

This is true of anything that is a subtype of `Iterable`; that is, anything that can produce an `Iterator`.  So, the `Collection` classes are covered.

Illustrated: Your enhanced-for is doing this under the covers:

```
for(Iterator<Apple> iterator = apples.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Apple apple = iterator.next();
    if(apple.getColour().equals(colour)) {
        dosomething();
        return apple;
    }
 }
```

Comment: do you mean that first red apple in the list will be returned and the method stops at that poit?

Comment: Yes.  Since you `return`, there's no way that the iterator can continue (this is a termination of the current execution of your operation, or "completes abruptly").

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedList<E>` is a container with the defined order: its order of iteration corresponds to the order in which the items have been added to the list. Since your `for` loop terminates as soon as it finds an apple of the requested color, the first red apple will be returned. Of course if the list contains no red apples, `null` will be returned.

The same is true about other kinds of lists (e.g. an array list). However, other containers may behave differently. For example, `TreeSet<E>` would order its elements in a way that may be different from the insertion order; `HashSet<E>` would return its elements in an arbitrary order, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The for each loop uses the Iterable interface's iterator method to acquire the iterator for the collection you are iterating over.  If you look at the Javadoc for LinkedList you will see that its iterator() method is inherited from the AbstractSequentialList class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html#iterator()

The documentation for it states:

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this list (in proper
>   sequence).

So yes, you will get the first red apple.